# Automatically generate <a> tag from <img> tag

Tags: javascript, html

I have a page where the following pattern happens quite often:

```
<a href="path/to/image.jpg">
    <img src="path/to/image.jpg">
</a>
```

In order to avoid typos, I'd prefer to only have to enter the image and path once.

Is there a way (preferably using only native HTML/JS/CSS) to avoid that duplication?

Only recent browsers need to be supported.

**Edited to add:** there's one location in the page that has a similar but possibly conflicting pattern:

```
<a href="https://a.web.site/">
    <img src="image.jpg">
</a>
```

I could get rid of it if needed.
But maybe a more robust solution would be to start from something like:

```
<a href="path/to/image.jpg">
    IMG_LINK_TO_CREATE
</a>
```

and to replace a predefined pattern with the img tag, rather than the other way around.

Comment: I don't think that's necessary. Better to write simple clean code rather than complex code that does the same thing.

Comment: @jmr i fixed this, have a look in answers

Comment: are you open to use jquery?

Comment: I’d recommend a template-based static page generator. There are lots of decent ones. Anything with JavaScript (like all of the existing answers) is unnecessary complexity that comes with a *lot* of downsides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fit my answer to your question, I'll only use **Vanilla JavaScript**. Also, since it's not clear for me if you are trying to create an img from an anchor or viceversa, I am doing both for you. I'll put first the one that appears in you question title.

### Identify your elements:

If you want this to work, you need to give at least a class or unique id attribute to your anchor tag in order to properly modify it later on when they are loaded into the DOM.

#### Generate anchor tag for an image tag

For this case, since you probably will be using multiple anchors and you'll have to do the same for every anchor you want, a class attribute with "create-link" would be enough for you to easily modify these elements directly from the DOM. Something like this would help:

```
<img class="create-link" src="path/to/image.jpg">
```

With this said, you can create a function called `generateImages()` which will do all the work.

```
function generateImages(){
   let images = document.querySelectorAll(".create-link");
   images.forEach(image=>{
      let link = document.createElement('a'),
            parent = image.parentNode,
          childImage = new Image();
      link.href = image.src;
      link.classList.add('generated-link');
      childImage.src = image.src;
      link.append(childImage);
      image.parentNode.removeChild(image);
      parent.append(link);
   });
}
```

And that should do it. You can now just execute it whenever you want or in the window load event.

`window.onload = generateImages;`

Here is a fiddle to help you visualize the overall of this method.

https://jsfiddle.net/m90b6vc5/1/

#### Generate image from anchor tag:

Same thing as the other one, identify your elements that you will need to use in JavaScript in the future.
The code would be a little bit easier to this, just need to retrieve the link from the anchor tag and append it to a new image element:

```
function generateImages(){
   let a = document.querySelectorAll(".create-link");
   a.forEach(element=>{
      let image = new Image();
      image.src = element.href;
      element.append(image);
   });
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/m90b6vc5

Comment: Thanks for your help everyone. I read and anlayzed each answer, and in particular, the design rationale behind each one. I agree that the idea of doing it client-side in pure JS is a bad idea in general, but in my specific context (where implementation speed, integrity and "pureness" trump performance), it's still the one that makes sense. I'm accepting this answer, since it's well explained... and is the one that I ended up implementing. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

javascript function

```
function createImageStructure(number, imageArray){ var structure = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < number; i++){
       structure += '<a href="'+imageArray[i]+'"> <img src="'+imageArray[i]+'"> </a>';
    } console.log(structure); }


var imageArray = [];
imageArray.push("https://pay.google.com/about/static/images/social/knowledge_graph_logo.png");

imageArray.push("https://pay.google.com/about/static/images/social/knowledge_graph_logo.png");

createImageStructure(2, imageArray);
```

output

```
<a href="https://pay.google.com/about/static/images/social/knowledge_graph_logo.png"> <img src="https://pay.google.com/about/static/images/social/knowledge_graph_logo.png"> </a><a href="https://s23527.pcdn.co/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/google-photos.png"> <img src="https://s23527.pcdn.co/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/google-photos.png"> </a>
```

basically, create a function, create an array, to have image paths, this will help to create HTML structure with multiple images.

if need more help please let me know, i will fix this, if you want just one image source path for all img tags

Comment: My apologies for the delay. I posted the question right before going to bed.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this. But note that this only adds the img after the page is loaded. which means the users view can be re-rendered after the page loads. You can control it to some extent by defining the expected img with-height or ratio in the .img-link class using css

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.img-link').each(function(){
    $(this).append($('<img src="' + $(this).attr('href') + '" />'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="path/to/image.jpg" class="img-link"></a>
<a href="custom-link">
  <img src="custom-image.jpg" />
</a>
<a href="path/to/image.jpg" class="img-link"></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

While I really don't want to encourage you to do this with client-side code, I will at least suggest you use code that generates links instead of code that generates images. This way, the website still shows images if the JS doesn't run.

The simplest way to do this is to add a class to all images which you want to automatically wrap in a link, such as "auto-link", and then run this code:

```
for (const img of document.querySelectorAll(".auto-link")) {
    const link = document.createElement("a");
    link.href = img.src;
    img.parentElement.replaceChild(link, img);
    link.appendChild(img);
}
```

You can put this in an "domready" or "load" event listener, or just in a script tag at the end of the page.

Note that pretty much all browsers have a "view image" option in their context menu, so there's no reason to do this. You shouldn't introduce a dependency on JavaScript, which slows down execution and wont work if you disable JS or use a screen reader. Instead, features like these ought to be  done server-side  or as a compilation  step.

Answer (score 1):

A good way to encapsulate your html and reuse it elsewhere is React.

```js
function AImg({ href, src }) {
  return <a href={ href || src }>
    <img src={ src }/>
  </a>;
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <AImg src="https://placecage.com/./200/200" />
    <AImg src="https://placecage.com/c/200/200" href="https://placecage.com"/>
    <AImg src="https://placecage.com/g/200/200" />
  </div>, 
  document.getElementById('aimg_container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="aimg_container"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

React.js is good way to go. If you want to still use ES6 only you can use also backticks. Add links to images and links in an array and in a `for of` loop create links with image. Something like:

```
const urls = ['1', '2', '3'];
const images = ['a','b','c'];
let links = [];

for (let index of urls.keys()) {
  links.push(`
    <a href="${urls[index]}"><img src="${images[index]}" /></a>
  `);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding elements to the DOM can be expensive. I would not be adding `a` tags via javascript. Keep your HTML mostly as is, but leave the `href` attribute empty for the links you want to populate.

I've also given you the option of populating the image source based on the `href`. This is not as good as the image has to be loaded after the page is rendered.

```js
//Wait for everything to be loaded
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
  //Find a tags with empty hrefs
  let emptyAs = document.querySelectorAll("a[href='']");
  emptyAs.forEach((a) => {
    //Update href based on image src
    a.href = a.querySelector("img").src;
  });
  
  //Alternatively Find images with empty src
  let emptyImgs = document.querySelectorAll("img[src='']");
  emptyImgs.forEach((img) => {
    img.src = img.parentNode.href;
  });
  
  
});
```

```html
<a href="">
  <img src="https://fillmurray.com/200/200" />
</a>
<a href="">
  <img src="https://fillmurray.com/100/100" />
</a>

<a href="https://fillmurray.com/300/300">
  <img src="" />
</a>


<a href="http://www.google.com">
  <img src="https://fillmurray.com/400/400" />
</a>
```

Note `forEach` has no IE support for a node list: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I just benchmarked (with performance.now() before and after the code) the "img[src='']" variant with a page containing ~280 occurences on Firefox 60. Compared to the accepted solution (new Image()) solution, the performance roughly the same (~450ms in both cases, which is acceptable in this use case).